# adding functions to auto generated form code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i am currently working with code generated through the netbeans IDE form builder. i also have a class with a function that allows images to be selected and moved using the click and draglistener functions

with other functions i have been able to call my drag class to a non-generated form as so:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    DragPanel dragPanel = new DragPanel();
    MyFrame(){
        this.add(dragPanel);    
        this.setTitle("drag and drop demo");
        this.setSize(1500,1200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

but when i attempt to add my code to the constructor which also runs autogenerated functions such as initComponents() the pictures do not appear, however i know that the call works due to a print function to test whether the function is accessed

i have tried using all functions i know of to add the pictures to a panel, this.add , add. , just the call "DragPanel dragPanel = new DragPanel();" but to no avail, i believe it may be possible the pictures are hidden behind the background but i do not think so

i also know that the pictures are accessable due to me being able to call them from a different test panel

also the dimensions of the frame do not matter

auto generated class:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    MRM mrm = new MRM();
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        this.add(mrm);
        
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 803, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 480, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

drag pictures function

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class MRM extends JPanel{
     boolean dragValid = false;
     ImageIcon topMiddle = new ImageIcon("top center.PNG");
     final int WIDTH = topMiddle.getIconWidth();
     final int HEIGHT = topMiddle.getIconHeight();
     Point imageCorner;
     Point prevPT;
    
    MRM() {
        imageCorner = new Point(0, 0);
        ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener();
        DragListener dragListener = new DragListener();
        this.addMouseListener(clickListener);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(dragListener);
        System.out.print("test");
    }
    
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        topMiddle.paintIcon(this, g, (int) imageCorner.getX(), (int) imageCorner.getY());
     }
      private class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            prevPT = e.getPoint();
            dragValid = (e.getPoint().getX() > imageCorner.getX()) &&
                    (e.getPoint().getX() < (imageCorner.getX() + WIDTH)) &&
                    (e.getPoint().getY() > imageCorner.getY()) &&
                    (e.getPoint().getY() < (imageCorner.getY() + HEIGHT));
        }
      }
        private class DragListener extends MouseMotionAdapter {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (dragValid) {
                Point currentPt = e.getPoint();
                imageCorner.translate(
                        (int) (currentPt.getX() - prevPT.getX()),
                        (int) (currentPt.getY() - prevPT.getY())
                );
                prevPT = currentPt;
                repaint();

            }
            }
        }
      }
```

this is as minimal as i can get the code, picture will need to be changed to something elsen initComponents class is essentially empty.

Comment: Honestly (opinion though): if you are doing this to learn about how to do UI coding with Swing: then do **not** start with any IDE generating code for you. Instead: sit down, and write things all yourself, because A) that helps you to really learn how swing works and more importantly B) it prevents that you come up with such questions. What I mean is: when you generate UI code, that doesn't come for free. As you just noticed: that code follows certain "ideas". And if you dont understand those, you are basically lost. Which results: not only do you have to learn about Swing

Comment: but you ALSO have to (first) learn/understand how the tool you are using "thinks", and what it does, and how you make good use of it.

Comment: yeah this isnt my code i prefer to do it manually but this is for a group work and i have to add my function to the auto generated code ive never worked with before

Comment: Then the most meaningful strategy, in my eyes: to sit down with the members of your group. You should always prefer to communicate with "real" humans you have direct access to and that KNOW all your context, compared to sending such "complicated" things to strangers on the internet. You see, in order to help you, we need a [mcve] ... and I dont see that here.

Comment: Guessing here: instead of doing `this.add(mrm)` try if you can use `getContentPane().add()` ...

Comment: no luck im afraid

Comment: What happens when you dont use your MRM JPanel, but something much simpler, maybe just something that displays a button or label? When your "complicated" code doesnt work, then look at the different components it has, and try (for each one) to make them "more simple".

Comment: when i use a normal jPanel it works and the image appears, but even in an empty generated Jframe it will not appear

Comment: Yeah well, I think your MRM JPanel has no way of telling how "big" it is? You see, Swing layout managers try to figure "what dimensions does that thing I should render have". Worst case: have your IDE override all the methods that JPanel comes with. Then add print statements in each one to understand the way your panel methods get invoked, and when. I would guess: at some point the owning layout asks the panel for its dimensions, and the panel doesnt give a proper response. But just guessing here, it is like 20 years since I last worked with swing for real.